# How can we make session to not to use cookies?

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

I got this is in my homework question. Help Please

Comment: you should DO your homework, rather than ask others to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

The basic idea is that you place information in the url instead of the cookie

Answer (score 7):

By setting the [cookieless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) property to `true` in `web.config`:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the session ID in the url instead, however this is more open to security holes (for instance when people share a URL, the session ID is still there)

Answer (score 3):

It's a config entry in the web.config file.

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx